# Execute R script with hotkey

Tags: r, bash, autohotkey

Let's assume I have an R script located in `C:\Users\user\myscript.R`. How can I assign a hotkey (e.g., `F1`) so that every time that I press that hotkey the R script will be executed in the background (i.e., without opening Rstudio)?

Note:
I use Windows 10 and have AutoHotkey installed which might help to bind the script to the key.

Comment: Have AutoHotkey execute `Rscript --vanilla filename`?

Comment: I'm not sure, I only have a very basic knowledge of AutoHotKey, but I'll have a look.

Comment: Maybe use [`Run`](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm)

Comment: I tried `Run, C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\Rscript.exe, C:\Users\user\myscript.R` without success. Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Run a `.bat` file with `"...\Rscript.exe" "...\myscript.R"` written in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution involves three steps:

1) Create a `.bat` file that executes the R script (as suggested by Daniel O):

**runscript.bat** (located in `C:\Users\user\runscript.bat`)

```
"C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\R.exe" CMD BATCH "C:\Users\user\myscript.R"
```

2) Bind the `.bat` script to the `Home` hotkey with the open-source software [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) by creating a `.ahk` script (as suggested by D. Pardal):

**bindscript.ahk** (located in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\StartUp` so it will automatically load-up on start-up, see [this](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/FAQ.htm#Startup))

```
Home::Run, runscript.bat, C:\Users\user
```

3) Set environment variable for R on windows 10 following [this tutorial](http://yizhexu.com/2017/02/r-path/).

Comment: No reason really to create a batch file. The run command can do it just fine: `Run, % """C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\R.exe"" CMD BATCH ""C:\Users\user\myscript.R"""` or if running it via cmd is important: `Run, % A_ComSpec " /c ""C:\Program Files\R\R-4.0.0\bin\R.exe"" CMD BATCH ""C:\Users\user\myscript.R"""`. Also didn't specify a working directory, since it's more than likely of no use. Though, no way for us to know.

Answer (score 0):

press win+r, type "shell:startup", and press enter. It should bring up file explorer. There, you can create a different script and write this inside it:

```
F1:: 
Run, C:\Users\user\myscript.R
```

This will make the trigger script run at startup, so that whenever you press f1, myscript.r will run